# How to compute the sum of the element-wise minimum of each pair of vectors of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I have a `(n, m)` matrix `M` composed of `n` vectors of length `m`.

I want to compute a matrix `K` of dimensions `(n, n)`, where in position `(i, j)` there is the sum of the element-wise minimum vector between the original vector `i` and vector `j`.

So, for example, if the matrix `M` has the vector `i` equal to `[ 2, 5, 4 ]` and the vector `j` equal to `[ 3, 1, 6 ]`, the element-wise minimum vector is `[ 2, 1, 4 ]`, and the sum of this vector is `7`. Therefore, in the matrix `K` in position `(i, j)` there has to be `7`.

Of course, it is not that difficult to do this using for-loops, but I want to compute `K` **using only vectorized operations of NumPy** since the matrix `M` is huge and using standard operations like loops is very slow.

Can someone help me?

I already tried using `np.minimum.outer(M)`, which outputs a `(n, m, n, m)` matrix `Z` where the value in `(i, j, k, l)` is the minimum between the value `M(i, j)` and `M(k, l)` in the original matrix, so computing for each value of `M` a matrix with the minimum between that value compared with all the elements in `M`.

The problem is that I still haven't figured out how to correctly sum the elements of Z using NumPy operations.

Comment: `K=np.minimun(M[:,None,:], M[None,::])` should make a `(n,n,m)` array.   Then `K.sum(axis=-1)` to get (n,n) array.

Comment: That works so good!  Using broadcasting like that is brilliant, you solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get all pairs of rows you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with `repeat=2`. Then, you can use that to index the array to get the row pairs, perform the element-wise minimum, sum it, and reshape it to your desired square.

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

arr = np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)
perms = np.array(list(product(range(arr.shape[0]), repeat=2)))
minimums = np.minimum(arr[perms[:,0]], arr[perms[:,1]])
res = minimums.sum(1).reshape(arr.shape[0], arr.shape[0])
```

Result:

```py
array([[10, 10, 10, 10],
       [10, 35, 35, 35],
       [10, 35, 60, 60],
       [10, 35, 60, 85]])
```

Intermediates:

```py
# arr
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

# perms
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 0],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 3]])

# minimums
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

# minimums.sum(1)
array([10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 35, 35, 35, 10, 35, 60, 60, 10, 35, 60, 85])
```

Comment: I was thinking of using broadcasting` to get the pairs, `K=np.minimun(M[:,None,:], M[None,::])`.  Can't test that now.

Comment: @hpaulj You're right as usual. You can just do `np.minimum(M[:,None], M).sum(-1)`. I wish I could see how that works but it will take me some time to work it out and understand it... Ugh.